# fill the background of a div with a <img>

Tags: html, css

I want to fill the background of a div with a photo img similar to the way you would use CSS background-size cover; but in this case it needs to be an img because this is page content and will eventually be coming from our CMS. 
Here is what I have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmBRPR?editors=110#0 
This is what I want it to look like but I don’t want to use CSS background: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpBmYz?editors=110 
I’m not using Less and my HTML is more basic than [setting an image to fill the background of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15249966/5399165)

```
  <aside class="row cross-link">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a class="cross-link-item" href="#"><h5 class="cross-link-text">Local Events</h5><img class="hero" src="http://ridebike.ws/images/heros/Trance-27.5-003x300.jpg"alt=""/></a>
    <a class="cross-link-item" href="#"><h5 class="cross-link-text">Local Events</h5><img class="hero" src="http://ridebike.ws/images/heros/Trance-27.5-003x300.jpg"alt=""/></a>
    <a class="cross-link-item" href="#"><h5 class="cross-link-text">Local Events</h5><img class="hero" src="http://ridebike.ws/images/heros/Trance-27.5-003x300.jpg"alt=""/></a>
 </div>

 </aside>
```

and

```
.cross-link {
  background-color: #7bafd0;
  padding-right: 4%;
  padding-left: 4%;
  text-align: center;
}

a.cross-link-item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #1f26ab;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cross-link-text {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: It's coming from your CMS? Why does it need to be an `img`? Why can't you just spit out the following: `<div style='background-image: url(path/to/img)'></div>`

Comment: Agreed, you can populate in CSS just as easily as HTML with a CMS.

Comment: Maybe but this will end up being part of the content of the page, I want it to print if the user should want to do that, and I'm trying to keep CSS out of my HTML.

Comment: will this answer work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by positioning both the text and the image relative to the div and specifying a width and height on the div the desired effect can be achieved.

check out the code pen: http://mbs.red/postion